# How to make a function return an output

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make an application which will ask the user whether to detect a text/ logo, however the application is not returning any result. The application will first open a Tkinter window with two buttons Text / Logo, if the user selects Text, a camera will open up where the user can detect text and after pressing "q" it will terminate and SHOULD return an output that was detected, however it doesn't.

I have tried to play around with return and print statement but got no luck.

Here is the code i am using:

```
import argparse
import io
import cv2
from google.cloud import vision
from google.cloud.vision_v1 import types
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


def window():
    # Create an instance of Tkinter frame
    win = Tk()
    win.title("Logo/ Text")
    # Set the geometry of Tkinter frame
    win.geometry("400x250")

    # Create Buttons with proper position
    button1 = ttk.Button(win, text="Logo", command=take_logo)
    button1.pack(side=TOP)
    button2 = ttk.Button(win, text="Text", command=take_text)
    button2.pack(side=TOP)

    win.mainloop()

def close():
   win = Tk()
   win.quit()

def take_logo():
    close()
    while True:
        _, frame = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow("window", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.imwrite("processing_picture.jpg", frame)
            break
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Instantiates a client
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    # Loads the image into memory
    with io.open("processing_picture.jpg", 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = types.Image(content=content)

    # Performs label detection on the image file
    response = client.logo_detection(image=image)
    annotations = response.logo_annotations
    for annotation in annotations:
        logo_result = annotation.description
    return logo_result


def take_text():
    close()
    while True:
        _, frame = capture.read()
        cv2.imshow("window", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord("q"):
            cv2.imwrite("processing_picture.jpg", frame)
            break
    capture.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

    # Instantiates a client
    client = vision.ImageAnnotatorClient()

    # Loads the image into memory
    with io.open("processing_picture.jpg", 'rb') as image_file:
        content = image_file.read()

    image = types.Image(content=content)

    # Performs label detection on the image file
    response = client.text_detection(image=image)
    labels = response.text_annotations
    for label in labels:
        text_result = label.description
    return text_result


window()
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Where exactly do you expect it to be returned?  `window()` doesn't return anything at all.  Your `take_logo` and `take_text` functions return something, but they each only return one item out of an iteration, which is probably not what you want -- and since you're hooking those functions up to buttons, the return value doesn't go anywhere anyway (but again, even if it did, `window` doesn't return it -- and the caller of `window()` wouldn't do anything with it if it did).

Comment: Why does `close()` create a new TK window that it just closes immediately?

Comment: @Samwise, If you look in the take_text and take_logo function, you can see that after pressing "q", the program will capture the resukt and window() should return that result. e.g window() opens, i click on "Text", take_text function starts running then i press "q" for it to capture text and afte that window() should return that captured text. I hope it is clear.

Comment: `window` doesn't have a `return` statement anywhere in its body, so it won't ever return anything.  Additionally, the place where you call `window()` in your code doesn't do anything with that return value.  That makes me think that when you say "return" you mean something other than the normal meaning of the word -- so where do you want that result to *go*?  What does the word "return" mean to you in this context?  Do you want these values to get printed to the console?  Displayed in some other UI widget?

Comment: Idealy i want text_result and logo_result to store a certain value (e.g. text_result = hello, logo_Result = asos). In short i want these values to be printed in a console.

Comment: What if you did `for annotation in annotations: print(annotation.description)` instead of trying to store `annotation.description` in a `logo_result` variable?

Comment: The problem with just returning the value is that UI programming is usually asynchronous; a lot of things will happen *after* the function that sets up them returns.  So you need to think really carefully about *where* the value is going to be used, and *when*.  If you just want to print the value to the console, and you don't particularly care when, the obvious solution is to just print it as soon as it's available rather than trying to store it somewhere.

Comment: @Samwise, the initial application consists of other functions which are used for an object detection. So after text or logo detection comes an object detection.

Comment: @Samwise When a certain object has been detected i will then use that data for example text = harry potter, and detected object = book, to combine it all in a url where a user can look for this product. the URL is located at the end of the application so thats why i am thinking i need to store text_result and logo_result so i  can use in the variable at the end of my application. Not sure how i can move this data from take_logo() or take_text() to the end of my application.